# I am unable to bind to an LDAP server due to "Invalid Credentials", though the credentials are valid

Tags: php, ldap

I'm setting up a php page to connect to an LDAP server but for some reason it will not let me connect.  At first I thought that my credentials had not been set up correctly, but after entering them into Softerra LDAP browser I was able to connect there.

```
<?php 
    $url = "ldaps://ldap.XXX.XXXX.edu:PORT/o=XXXX.edu";
    $ldap_user = "uid=XXXXXXXX,ou=Campus Accounts,o=XXXX.edu";
    $ldap_pass = "XXXXXXXX";

    ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
    $conn = ldap_connect($url) or die ("Could not connect to server");
    if ($conn)
    {
        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) ;
        $bind = ldap_bind($conn, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass);
    }
?>
```

But all that I get back is the following message.

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

Is there something extra I need to do to the user data to get it to be accepted?

Comment: I think you're formatting the user wrong in `$ldap_user`. Try just domain\user.

Comment: like "XXXX.edu/uid=XXXXXXXX"?  I tried that in place of $ldap_user and got a "Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Operations error" error instead.

Comment: I meant more like XXXX.edu\XXXXXXXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting to Active Directory (which is implied by the o=XXX.edu style notation (though if so, incorrect)) and by the comment suggestions of trying to bind as xxxx.edu\xxxx then the root most nodes in Active Directory are always dc= not o= and therefore a more correct bind DN or base DN would most likely finish as:

dc=xxx,dc=edu